# Cannot launch R help document from terminal R

Tags: linux, r

My working platform is:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.1 (jessie)
Release:    8.1
Codename:   jessie
```

I have installed vim-r-plugin for editing and running R programs. Everything looks fine but launch some R help document such as:

[image]

Does somebody know what's the reason and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you type `getOption("help_type")` it will be either `"html"` or `"text"`. If it is `"html"` then it tries to open help in the browser. Here the browser it is trying to open doesn't seem to exist. You can change the browser by typing the command `options(browser = "firefox")`.
If you're using Debian Jessie you might need to use `options(browser = "iceweasel")`.

If you instead want to get help to display in the terminal, type `options(help_type = "text")`.

To make your desired options happen automatically every time you start R, put your desired `options()` settings in your `~/.Rprofile`.

Comment: I think the default is NULL though which will still open as if you used "text"